# anycharts.com component scroller is showing both fill and selectedfill as same color

Tags: angular, typescript, anychart, anychart-8.2

i am using anycharts gantt component in one of my angular components which have scroll bar as in

```
const  timeLineScroller = this.chart.xScroller();
         timeLineScroller.fill('gray');
      timeLineScroller.selectedFill('lightGray');
```

so this code will make the SCroll bar in Gray Color and Selected Scroll area as Light Gray 
the problem i am facing is when i move from one component to other and open the same component later with out refreshing the page i am able to see both fill and SekectedFill as gray

but if i refresh the page then i am able to ger desired output of fill as gray and selectedfill as light gray

so can any one help me in resetting Settings? even without refreshing  the page

Answer (score 1):

The Angular environment requires some specific settings to avoid rendering issues sometimes. Try to add the line `anychart.graphics.useAbsoluteReferences(false);` before the chart configuration code. This should solve the issue.